# Leer respuesta array multidimensional de API smsgateway.me

Tags: php

Estoy probando el envio sms de https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messages/send-message-to-number

Yo logro enviar el mensaje correctamente, lo que no se es como leer correctamente la respuesta del array que da como resultado
me produce esta respuesta
Exito:

```
Array ( [response] => Array ( [success] => 1 [result] => Array ( [success] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 24221330 [device_id] => 30006 [message] => Hello World 5! [status] => pending [send_at] => 1474902591 [queued_at] => 0 [sent_at] => 0 [delivered_at] => 0 [expires_at] => 1474906131 [canceled_at] => 0 [failed_at] => 0 [received_at] => 0 [error] => [created_at] => 1474902553 [contact] => Array ( [id] => 5226653 [name] => Noel [number] => +54412512554 ) ) ) [fails] => Array ( ) ) ) [status] => 200 )
```

Yo quisiera validar si el envió se envió se envió correctamente pero no se como acceder al array para ver si fue enviado.

Esta es la respuesta cuando es fallido:

```
Array ( [response] => Array ( [success] => 1 [result] => Array ( [success] => Array ( ) [fails] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [number] => +544782548 [message] => Hello World 5! [device] => 30005 [send_at] => 1474915203 [expires_at] => 1474918743 [email] => correo@gmail.com [password] => aaaa [errors] => Array ( [device] => Array ( [0] => The selected device is invalid. ) ) ) ) ) ) [status] => 200 )
```

Comment: Pero para validar si es que es erróneo o exitoso el envio, ¿no debieras mirar el objeto fail o success?

Si response.result.success es vacio... debiera ser error... ¿o no?

Comment: hola que mas, si buena idea. Lo ise de la siguiente manera:                      if (!isset($result['response']['result']['fails']['0']))   {
  echo "exito";} else { $error='Ocurrio un Error';
   if (isset($result['response']['result']['fails']['0']['errors']['device']['0'])) $error=$result['response']['result']['fails']['0']['errors']['device']['0'];           echo $error}

Answer (score 1):

si buena idea. Lo ise de la siguiente manera:

```
if (!isset($result['response']['result']['fails']['0'])) { echo "exito";} 
else { 
$error='Ocurrio un Error'; 
if (isset($result['response']['result']['fails']['0']['errors']‌​['device']['0'])) $error.=$result['response']['result']['fails']['0']['errors']‌​['device']['0'];  echo $error;}
```